# how to customize index.html while running ng build

Tags: angular, angular10, angular12, angular13

When ever I'm running ng build its generating content from in index.html file.

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>NgCli</title>
      <base href="/">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    </head>
    
    <body>
    
      <app-root></app-root>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="es2015-polyfills.js" nomodule></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
    
    </html>
```

Is any way to generate only style and script tag  without html tags like below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js">
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="es2015-polyfills.js" nomodule>
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: No, but you can create a custom js script that will simply generate this content after the build is done. Like `npm run build && node your_script.js`

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway? If you have to do anything like this I'd recommend looking for a different solution. I assume you want to append this on another index.html file you already have, so just add whatevers missing to the Angular project instead of the other way around.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi can we get environment details there to know whether it is dev or prod

Comment: Yes, by making two scripts.